# opamp dc comparator

Tags: comparator, single-supply-op-amp, light-sensor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNuy8w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to compare the voltages of the inverting and non-inverting terminal but no matter what input I put in, the voltages seem to be the same at the input terminals and the output is always high. I am using an LM393P. even if I use voltage dividers, the input is the same. kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you [edit] to remove the shouting from the title, please? Show your circuit schematic and mark the measured voltages. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: my simulation works just fine. but when i go to the bread board it is not working

Comment: We can't see your schematic, we can't see your simulation, we can't see your breadboard. How do you expect help?

Comment: i have placed the simulation. it is a single supply opamp. the input at the inverting and non inverting terminals goes to the same level no matter the voltage divider i use and the led is always on

Comment: i am using a power supply from a 12v voltage regulator(lm7812) regulator providing a maximum of 50mA.

Comment: Take a voltmeter and measure the output voltages of your divider and make sure they are what they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3mG34.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The rearranged simulation circuit. R1 is now a variable resistor and it can be used in the CircuitLab DC sweep function. Note that R5 has been increased to 1k to prevent overloading the op-amp output.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The results of the sweep varying R1 from 50 kΩ to 150 kΩ. The switching action is correct. As the inverting input voltage exceeds that of the non-inverting input the output switches low.*

Comment: let me try it. i will let you know

Comment: thanks alot for your help... it worked